# Assigning card colour to the deck of cards in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SUITS 4
#define RANKS 13
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define MAX 9
    typedef struct
    {
        char *rank;
        char *suit;
        char *colour;

    }Card;

    Card* make_deck();
    void print(Card*);
    void shuffle(Card*);
    void print_to_file(FILE *, Card *);

    int main()
    {
        Card *deck = make_deck();

        printf(" ***************Original Deck ***************\n");

        print(deck); /*print original deck */

        printf("\n\n ***************Shuffled Deck ***************\n");

        shuffle(deck);

        print(deck); /*print shuffled deck */

        printf("\n");

        return 0;

    }

    Card* make_deck()
    {
        /*You may want to use these arrays to point rank and suit to, or to strcpy from. Your choice which
         *you choose */
        char *ranks[] = { "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2",
            "Ace" };

        char *suits[] = { "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };
        char *colours[] = { "Red", "Black" };

        /*allocate space for 52 cards on the heap */
        Card *deck = (Card*) malloc(DECK_SIZE *(sizeof(Card)));

        for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            /*Set the ranks,suits and colours of the cards  */
            deck[i].rank = ranks[i % RANKS];

            deck[i].suit = suits[i / RANKS];
            deck[i].colour = colours[i];

        }

        return deck;

    }

    /*print the deck to the screen (see sample output on assignment sheet). */
    void
    print(Card *deck)
    {
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            printf("%5s %-12s", deck[i].suit, deck[i].rank);

            if (0 == ((i + 1) % 3))
            {
                printf("\n");

            }
        }
    }

    /*traverse the deck, one card at a time, swapping the current card
     *with a randomly chosen card from the deck
     */
    void
    shuffle(Card *deck)
    {
        int swap = 0;   //index of card to be swapped
        int i = 0;  //counter
        Card temp = { "", "" }; //temp holding place for swap
        srand(time(NULL));  //seed the random numbers with current time
        for (i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            //generate a pseudo-random number from 0 to 51
            swap = rand() % DECK_SIZE;

            //swap current card with da swapper
            temp = deck[i];

            deck[i] = deck[swap];

            deck[swap] = temp;

        }
    }

    /*print the deck to a file */
    void
    print_to_file(FILE *filename, Card *deck) {}
```

In the above code, I'm storing the values of deck of cards and printing them in the terminal. But I have a problem. I want to print the color of the cards too. I made an array of colour

> char *colors = {"Red","Black"}

and stored it in the memory.
When I run the application, only first two cards get the color and the rest don't.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: `deck[i].colour = colours[i];` is the problem. You need to do something to modify `i` so it stays in the range of 0 to 1 as you did here: `deck[i].suit = suits[i / RANKS];`

Comment: Why is colour separate from suit? Are you expecting black diamonds or red spades? Also note your spelling inconsistency: Use `color` when coding, and "color" or "colour" as you see fit otherwise.